# MaterializeCSS Dropdown Link not clickable

Tags: wordpress, materialize

I'm experiencing a frustrating problem with MaterializeCSS dropdown links created on Wordpress Menus. I can see the link when I hover over the top level items, e.g. About FAIRDOM, but I can't click any of them. I know it's an issue somewhere perhaps in having a hidden element above that may be catching the click event, but I can't see where. Anyone with any idea of where the issue is in this site http://beta.fair-dom.org/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaterializeCSS built their dropdowns "mobile-first". Essentially, what that means for you is that the JS that powers the dropdowns explicitly disables the href on click for all dropdowns. This is a because, on mobile, a user cannot hover and can only touch.

However, if you're still wanting to get around this, you can try out the following (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
<script>
$('.dropdown-button').click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}
</script>
```

Try sticking that just before you close the body tag,

Comment: Thanks! I just came to the very same conclusion after taking away all JS. The strange thing is that I had it working for another site using materialise in the very same scenario. Could it be that they added this in more recently?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I'm fairly certain that it was the newest version. I recall something about a more mobile approach.